# Determine equation linking 2 variables

Tags: integration

I have some data with 3 variables *P*, *s* and *t*. I know that *P* is related to *s* as per the first equation below. I also know that *s* is equal to the area under a graph of *P* on the y-axis and *t* on the x-axis divided by a constant as per the second equation below. The *k* values are all constants.

$$P=k_1e^{-k_2s}$$

$$s=\frac1{k_3}\int_0^tPdt$$

Ideally, what I would like to find is an equation linking *P* and *t*, $P=f(t)$. My problem is that I do not know how to integrate the second equation as I am trying to integrate with respect to *dt* while *t* is one of the interval bounds. Does anyone know if this is possible and, if it is possible, what method should I use to find an equation linking *P* and *t*?

**Additional information:**

I am able to create a graph of *P* versus *t* using arrays in excel. I create an array of *t* (*t=0,1,2,3...*) and then use the following equations to calculate *P* and *s*, I can then plot *t* versus *P*. However as I say, ideally I would like to know an equation linking *P* and *t*.

$$P_n=k_1e^{-k_2s_n}$$

$$s_n=\frac1{k_3}\sum_{n=1}P_{n-1}\Delta t$$

$$s_0=0$$

This next paragraph is not important for the problem but I am just including it in case anyone is interested in the background to the problem. I am using battery charging data. *P* stands for Power, *s* for State of Charge (SoC) and *t* for time. The data shows that the power delivered to the battery decays exponentially with respect to SoC. SoC is calculated as the energy delivered to the battery (Power multiplied by time) divided by the total battery capacity ($k_3$). From this you can probably guess that I am an engineer and this is why I am struggling with the Maths!

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a differential equation. Let's say that $s$ and $P$ are both functions of $t$ (which, locally is true).

If you differentiate the second equation with regard to $t$, you get

$$s'(t) = \frac{1}{k_3} P(t)$$

where $s'=\frac{ds}{dt}$.

Plugging this into the first equation gives you 
$$P = k_1 e^{\frac{k_2}{k_3} P'}$$

or, if you take the logarithm of both sides and move $k_3$ to the left,

$$\log P - \log k_3 = \frac{k_2}{k_3} P'$$

With some rearangement, this becomes

$$P' = \alpha \log P - \beta$$

for some constants $\alpha, \beta$.

Luckilly for you, this is the simplest type of differential equation to solve as it has separable variables (because it is of the type $P' = f(P)\cdot g(t)$ for some pair of functions $f,g$-specifically, $g\equiv 1$). Do you know how to solve this kind of equation?